# Что бы не делался отрицательный баланс Discord. py SQL

Tags: python, sql, python-3.6, discord.py

я хочу что бы баланс когда баланс был меньше ста,то он не делал upgrade,и не снимал баланс.

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    name TEXT,
    id INT,
    cash BIGINT,
    rep INT,
    lvl INT,
    server_id INT,
    upgrade BIGINT
  )""")

  for guild in client.guilds:
    for member in guild.members:
      if cursor.execute(F"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1 ,{guild.id}, 10)")
        connection.commit()
      else:
        pass
  connection.commit()
  print('Бот присоеденился')









   @client.command()
    async def upgrade(ctx):
        cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET upgrade = upgrade + 10 WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id))
        cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash - 100 WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id))  
        connection.commit()  
        await ctx.send('улучшено')
```

Comment: *хочу что бы баланс когда баланс был меньше ста,то он не делал upgrade,и не снимал баланс.* Ну так добавь в структуру соответствующий CHECK constraint.

Comment: а как? я новичек в Sql

Comment: [SQLite Documentation - CREATE TABLE statement](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) -> "3.7. CHECK constraints".

Comment: разве это не будет конфликтовать перед другими апгрейдами?

Comment: Да понятия не имею... если не пересоздавать таблицу - то с какой бы стати? просто любая попытка вставить или обновить запись будет приводить к ошибке, если CHECK не выполняется, и всё.

Comment: А можно кодом?)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7438c15d3e181cf3f84dfed4fb87ece1